# django rest framework model habit tracker

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to do an habit tracker using django rest framework as backend and react-native as frontend. I have same issue with the model of data in django.
I want create one Daily instance for each date between start_date and end_date when a Tracker is created. Could you give me some help on how I can do it? Thank you in advance.

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from datetime import datetime


class Habit(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=360)


class Tracker(models.Model):
    habit = models.ForeignKey(Habit, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    start_date = models.DateField()
    end_date = models.DateField()
    published = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def is_active(self):
        today = datetime.now().date()
        return (today >= self.start_date) and (today <= self.end_date)


class Daily(models.Model):
    STATUS = [('DONE', 'DONE'), ('TODO', 'TODO'), ('NOTDONE', 'NOTDONE'),]
    date = models.DateField()
    status = models.CharField(choices=STATUS, max_length=10)
    tracker = models.ForeignKey(Tracker, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

**serializers.py**

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Habit, Tracker, Daily
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from rest_framework.authtoken.models import Token


class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['id', 'username', 'password']
        extra_kwargs = {'password': {'write_only': True, 'required': True}}

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = User.objects.create_user(**validated_data)
        Token.objects.create(user=user)
        return user


class HabitSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Habit
        fields = ['id', 'title', 'description']


class TrackerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Tracker
        fields = ['id', 'start_date', 'end_date', 'published', 'is_active', 'habit', 'user']


class DailySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Daily
        fields = ['id', 'date', 'status', 'tracker']
```

**views.py**

```
from rest_framework import viewsets
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from .models import Habit, Tracker, Daily
from .serializers import HabitSerializer, TrackerSerializer, DailySerializer, UserSerializer


class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer


class HabitViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Habit.objects.all()
    serializer_class = HabitSerializer


class TrackerViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Tracker.objects.all()
    serializer_class = TrackerSerializer

class DailyViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Daily.objects.all()
    serializer_class = DailySerializer
```

Comment: Can there be more than one Daily instance for a tracker on a given day?

Comment: no, just one. You can have multiple Daily instance with same date but with different tracker id (FK).

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend forcing the uniqueness check of `('tracker', 'date')` on the `Daily` model via [`unique_together`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/options/#unique-together). Then utilize the [`post_save`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/signals/#django.db.models.signals.post_save) signal to [create a receiver](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/signals/) to find newly created Tracker instance, then generate the Daily instances for each of the dates between the range. You could event use [`bulk_create`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create) to do so in fewer queries if you expect the range to be large.